# Graphite - Round values / set values precision

Tags: graphite

From summarize with average I get fractional values which I need to be rounded. What is more, it is important, that sum of rounded values is the same as not rounded (case when both has 0.5 would result in two ones not in one 0 and 1). Is there a function for something like that or at least a round function?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such a function. There is some issue on github https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/1346, but no resolution

**edit**

You can also add that function to file `<GRAPHITE_WEBAPP_DIR>/render/functions.py`:

```
def roundValues(requestContext, seriesList, ndigits):
  for series in seriesList:
    series.name = "roundValues(%s,%d)" % (series.name, ndigits)
    series.pathExpression = series.name
    for i,value in enumerate(series):
      if value is not None:
        series[i] = round(value, ndigits)
  return seriesList

# ...
# and to SeriesFunctions - almost at the bottom of file
SeriesFunctions = {
  # Combine functions
  'sumSeries' : sumSeries,
  'sum' : sumSeries,
  'roundValues': roundValues,
  # ...
}
```

After adding this, remove `*.pyc` file, restart uwsgi. You have now available function `roundValues`, it won't show up in menu but entering it by hand will work.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this issue but I was not sure why it was closed because there was no comment on that. Thank you.